# Does HTML5 require clients to support JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Does HTML 5 need JavaScript?

Or it is an option and I can use HTML5, CSS3 and GWT instead of JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: GWT uses javascript, first. Second, which parts of HTML5 interests you? That will help to answer your question.

Comment: Are you asking whether you need to *write* Javascript, or whether the client's browser must *support* it?

Answer (score 3):

**No, HTML5 does not *require* JavaScript**, although it does define a `<script>` element and it does define the `javascript:` protocol (an HTML5 UA should understand these, at least enough to ignore them). Imagine the case where a client browser simply 'disables all JavaScript, ever' (either by user-choice or because it does not support JavaScript).

This is backed by #4 in the [HTML 5 Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) under ["Running a script"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#running-a-script)

> If scripting is disabled for the script element, or if the user agent does not support the scripting language  given by the script block's type for this script element, then the user agent must abort these steps at this point. The script is not executed

JavaScript is, however, the only scripting language endorsed by the draft, assumes the role of the default language, and is listed as a 'dependency'.

Comment: `javascript:` is not a protocol.

Comment: @Excl It is per the HTML5 specification see [6.1.5 The javascript: protocol](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#javascript-protocol). (Also, it inhabits the protocol field -- really schema name -- of the URI. However, since that is where the similarity with a URL/URI ends...)

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a toolkit that allows you to write your code in Java and then debug. When it deploys it translates to JavaScript. So even though you really do not know you are writing Javascript the tool is generating it for you. GWT generated code runs on the browser.

HTML5 and CSS3 are tools for static web sites. If you add Javascript or GWT (Which is Javascript) then you can do more.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this to get idea of [HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/).