# Will HTML5 APIs work when Javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, api, html, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does HTML5 require clients to support JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327852/does-html5-require-clients-to-support-javascript)

Would HTML5 API's work when Javascript is disabled in the web browser? Or after HTML5 becomes standard is it true that we would no longer be able to disable Javascript?

I wrote a dummy chrome extension, that uses javascript to display a alert window.
This still works when I disable javascript, which I thought would disable it. Shouldn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: So the question is: "Will JavaScript in HTML5 work when JavaScript is disabled?"  I believe the answer is no.  And I've never heard that browser makers would take away the ability to disable JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "HTML5 API".

If you mean it as the DOM hooks into different elements, such as `video.play()`, then yes, you'll need JavaScript enabled to use those features.

If instead you mean it as the new features of HTML or CSS such as `input[type="email"]` and the `:valid` pseudo-selector, then no, you wont need JavaScript enabled to use those features.

---

Most of the new HTML5 features are targeted towards improving the interactivity and usability of the web. Any user who decided to disable JavaScript does so with the understanding that they are disabling the vast majority of web interactivity.

For a developer, this means that the interactions should be layered on top of a solid foundation of quality content and data. If the user has JavaScript enabled, then they get the flashier, easier to use interface. If the user has JS disabled, then they get the generic static content replacement.

Comment: Actually I was referring to the webkit API's supported by Chrome. And is this different for locally stored webpages (extensions/apps) and 'live' ones?

Comment: @source.rar, and ***why*** would you not add that information to the question?